# Cannot launch PSEXEC

Tags: c#, psexec

I have this very simple program

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"psexec";
process.Start();
```

But when I run it the debug says "The system cannot find the file specified"

If I have the same program and change "psexec" by "Notepad", it works and opens notepad.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"notepad";
process.Start();
```

This is weird because I have my psexec in the System32 and if run "psexec" using Windows-Run, it works.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**Update**: I specify the full path `@="C:\Windows\System32\PSexec.exe"` and It doesnt work. But If I move Psexec to, as example `@"D:\psexec.exe"` it works!!
Why coud  this happen?

Comment: Did you just install psexec? Try restarting stuff.

Comment: Did you try `psexec.exe` instead of `psexec`? Have a great day :)

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running programs from c:\windows\system32 is troublesome on a 64-bit operating system.  The workaround is Project + Properties, Build tab, change Platform target to AnyCPU.  Or to copy the file also to c:\windows\syswow64.

Or to just not put it in the Windows directory, it is not an operating system specific file that belongs there.  The appropriate place is the same directory as your EXE.

You can learn more about the File System Redirector in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try specify the full path of 'psexec'

there is any property 'WorkingDirectory', which might help.